# The script is not called in application.js.coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have view:

```
.form-actions
    %p= attach_links
    = f.button :submit, 'Add post', class: 'btn-bg'
    - if paid?
      = f.button :submit, 'save in ...', class: 'btn-inverse', name: 'draft'
    = button_tag 'Add poll', type: 'button', id: 'poll-btn', class: 'btn btn-bg'
    = link_to 'Cancel', blog_posts_path
```

When click button_tag 'Add poll' will display form for new Poll.

Its my script in **app/assets/javascript/application.js.coffee** for display form new poll:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#poll-btn').click ->
      if $('.poll').is(':visible')
        $('.poll').hide()
        $('#poll-btn').text 'Add poll'
        event.preventDefault()
      else
        $('.poll').show()
        $('#poll-btn').text 'Delete Poll'
        event.preventDefault()
      return
  return
```

**GEMFILE**

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1.1.0'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'oily_png'
  # gem 'font-awesome-rails'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
end
```

I click on button, but dont call my script. I cant undestand why. Can you help me solve this issue? Thank you.

**EDIT**

**part of application.js.coffee**

```
$(document).on 'click', '@load_more_comments', (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).html("<i class='icon icon-spin icon-refresh'></i> загрузка...")
  u = $(this).parent().find('@comments_list').data('u')
  l = $(this).parent().find('@comments_list').data('lastcid')
  $.ajax
    url: u
    dataType: 'script'
    method: 'GET'
    data:
      loadnew: l

$(document).ready ->
  $('#poll-btn').click ->
      if $('.poll').is(':visible')
        $('.poll').hide()
        $('#poll-btn').text 'Add poll'
        event.preventDefault()
      else
        $('.poll').show()
        $('#poll-btn').text 'Delete poll'
        event.preventDefault()
      return
  return


show_photo = (u) ->
  if window.innerWidth > 780
    $.fancybox.showLoading()
    $.ajax
      url: u
      method: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data:
        w: window.innerWidth
        h: window.innerHeight
  else
    document.location = u
```

Comment: what does your app/assets/javascript/application.js file have in it?

Comment: Have all code, about 3000 lines and all #= require... Today i runned server with production mode. But now again run with rails s and why dont work, i cant undestand

Comment: maybe problem with asset?